# Lightning rerender a force:recordView

Tags: lightning-aura-components, force

I've got a page that has a search box; selecting a result sets {v.id}

Underneath all that, I've got these two outputs:

```
<force:recordView recordID="{!v.id}" type="MINI"/>

<ui:inputText value="{!v.id}"/>
```

When {!v.id} gets changed, the force:recordView doesn't update, but the inputText does.  How do you make the recordView re-render?

I've tried wrapping in an aura:if to see if that would trigger it.  Also, this is being used outside sf1, if that matters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of Summer '15 this component still has server-side dependencies that prevent it from updating as desired. You will need create the component in JavaScript to achieve the desired result. Here's a small app that demonstrates this:

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL">
    <aura:attribute name="id" type="String" access="GLOBAL" default="001B0000003jUXI"/>
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.id}" action="{!c.updateRecordView}"/>
    <div aura:id="container">
        <force:recordView recordID="{!v.id}" type="MINI"/>
    </div>
    <ui:inputText value="{!v.id}"/>
</aura:application>
```

And the controller code:

```
({
    updateRecordView: function(component, event, helper) {
        var id = component.get("v.id");
        var container = component.find("container");
        $A.createComponent("force:recordView",
                           {recordId: id,type: "MINI"},
                           function(cmp) {
                               container.set("v.body", [cmp]);
                           });
    }
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Skip.  Do we have any way to document which components support auto-rerendering, just to save people time?