# Is it possible to display a record in the same page, with force:navigateToSObject

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In a lightning component, I have 2 div, one with a table for example, and in the other I want to display an object record (thanks to its id) and for tthat I have to use the `force:navigateToSObject` in the javascript controller of the component.

But when I use that, it redirects me to a "new" page (with the record) and I'd like to still see my first div (with the table) is there any way to do that ?

**EDIT**

I tried to use `force:recordView` in my component instead of `force:navigateToSObject` in the controller. But it gives me an error :

> Invalid Record Id or Record not accessible.

Here is a part of my component :

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<aura:handler event="c:NavigateToEvent" action="{!c.NavigateComponent}"/>

<aura:attribute name="id" type="String" access="GLOBAL"/>
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.id}" action="{!c.updateRecordView}"/>

{!v.body}
<!--{!v.eventCal}-->
<div id="container">
    <force:recordView recordID="{!v.id}" type="MINI"/>
</div>
```

and a part of the controller :

```
updateRecordView: function(component, event, helper) {
    var id = event.getParam("idEvent");
    var container = component.find("container");
    $A.createComponent("force:recordView",
                       {recordId: id,type: "MINI"},
                       function(cmp) {
                           container.set("v.body", [cmp]);
                       });
}
```

(I used this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82589/lightning-rerender-a-forcerecordview) to build that part of code)

Comment: y not use `force:recordView` tag  in the component markup instead of `force:navigateToSObject ` event to display the detail in the div?  won't it help in your case?

Comment: thanks for the idea @Praveen, there is so much functionnalities in lightning that I don't know they exists... ! But I tried what you mentionned and I can't make it works (I updated my post with the code)

Answer (score 2):

`force:recordView` component expected `recordId` but found `recordID` in your component markup, that is why you got the below error:

> *Invalid Record Id or Record not accessible*

It is because component attributes, variables you use in controller and helper are all case-sensitive.

With that said, `force:recordView` automagically refreshes the detail view when the `recordId` value change, so no need to create the same using `$A.createComponent` method.

Below is how your component should look.

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:handler event="c:NavigateToEvent" action="{!c.NavigateComponent}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="id" type="String" access="GLOBAL"/>

    {!v.body}
    <!--{!v.eventCal}-->
    <div id="container">
        <force:recordView recordId="{!v.id}" type="MINI"/>
    </div>
<aura:component
```

Comment: I change to `recordId` but I still get the same error. By the way, I tried to create dynamically the `force:recordView` by only write a `createComponent` in the controller but it doesn't work too...

Comment: @dou can you put an log to check whether `{!v.id}` contains valid record id or not?

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId"> 
    <aura:attribute name="id" type="String"/> 
    <force:recordView recordId="{!v.recordId}"/> 
</aura:component>
```

The reason is that `v.recordId` is already bound for you as documented here:

[Configure components for Record Specific Actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_lex_s1_config_action_recordid.htm)